# How can I simply this number format validation regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

So, I have this if statement:
`if (String(val).search(/^((\d+(((\,\d{3,})+)?)(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))$/) !== -1)`

Which says (as far as I am aware):
The string must either start with at least one digit, or a `.`.
If the string starts with a digit there can optionally be commas in the string, as long as the commas are followed by at least three digits.
If the string has a `.` in it, it must be followed by at least one digit.
There can be only one `.`

So, strings like:

5
5.00
5000
5,000
5000.00
5,000.00

Will all return true

But strings that contain anything but `0-9 , .` or are malformed will return false.
so strings like this:

5,00
5,00.00
5.00.00
a5

Now, the above works, but I am wondering if there is any way to simplify it?

Comment: Who downvoted without a comment? What's wrong with this question? I have an attempt to understand it, and get it working, so why the downvote? it's not like I am just saying, I want you to write this regex for me!

Comment: @ Hailwood: Neither of the downvotes is mine, but your title sets you up for downvotes even though the question doesn't (to my mind) warrant them. I recommend changing it to "How can I simplify this regex?" rather than demanding "Simplify this regex!"

Comment: Cheers, Title wasn't meant to be demanding, just concise ;) I have updated it to something a bit more friendly.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to improve some code, not simply trying to learn about regexes. You'll improve code more effectively by finding out and considering its purpose. Are you trying to prevent data entry errors? If so, do you need to permit South Asians to enter their customary format "100,00,00,000"? Or are you perhaps examining a database of numbers that are stored as strings? If that is the case, why are they stored that way?

Comment: @minopret Both really, The reason for the regex is that, if the value of a text input is considered valid, then it gets applied a jQuery plugin, otherwise it doesn't. It is also only going to be used in New Zealand Based Sites, and and such, the international money formats are not required for this regex, as for the learning, I have tried reading tutorials, and books etc, but I don't learn that way, I learn by doing, hence the, I'll do what I can, then share it here to see what can be improved for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove some redundant parenthesis:

```
^(\d+((\,\d{3,})+)?(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$
```

And something like `(( ... )+)?` can be replaced by: `( ... )*`, so the final regex might look like this:

```
^(\d+(\,\d{3,})*(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$
```

And if you'd like to reject input like:

```
50000,000,000.0
```

and only allow for:

```
5,000,000.0
50,000,000.0
500,000,000.0
```

Then do something like this:

```
^(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could simplify it, beyond stripping out a few parens, and as it is it's arguably not complex enough.  The pattern will also allow malformed strings such as

```
50000,000,000.000000000
```

Comment: Hmm, you are correct, So, I could replace both instances of `.\d+` with `.\d{2}` I believe. as for the first, part... Time to see if regex has lookbacks, so I can see if, before a comma there is either three digits, and then a comma, or at least one digit and the start of the line!

Comment: @Hailwood, you could replace `^(\d+...` with `^(\d{1,3}...`

Comment: Actually, I lie, That's too complex, `\d{3,3}` as opposed to `\d{3,}` should work

Comment: @Hailwood, I think we're talking about something different... See my edited answer for a fix. Also, `\d{3,3}` == `\d{3}`

Comment: @BartKiers Ah, yes, you are referring to the start of the string, which stops 50000 but if you only change that then 500,00000,000 is still valid, so if we combine them both and end up with `^(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$` then that will fix it and mean that only e.g. 5,000,000 is valid